# Is the structure "Who wants this ball to bang on their head?" acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, bare-infinitive, causative-verbs, catenative-verbs

I am proofreading an English book written by a non-native speaker.
A structure the author uses is the following

1. Who wants this ball bang on their head?

The meaning intended to be conveyed is: *Who wants this ball to hit them on the head?*

My first thought is that the sentence (1) should be as follows, with a *to* particle instead of a bare infinitive:

2. Who wants this ball **to** bang on their head?`

Is either of sentence (1) or (2) acceptable?

If both are acceptable, do they both mean exactly the same thing?

If neither is acceptable, what phrasing would be?

Comment: If it's dialog, better let it stand. After all, people talk any old way they please when issuing threats. And they may not please to be grammatically correct.

Comment: I'd go with (2), despite John's comment above.

Comment: "bang on their head" isn't very idiomatic "Who wants to get hit on the head with/by this ball?" is more natural, but that's not what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

"Bang on" means "precisely accurate" (see https://www.wordnik.com/words/bang%20on). "The ball was bang on his head" indicates the ball's trajectory resulted in an accurate hit to his head rather than a near miss.

In the same way "Who wants this ball bang on their head?" would mean "Who wants this ball to hit them (accurately) on the head?"

It is an odd use of "bang on" though unless it is a threat or an invitation to participate in soccer heading practice. Sentence 2 would normally be preferred.

Comment: This use as a preposition (with a noun complement) is exclusive to British English, as the article you linked says; I've never heard it in AmE.

Answer (score 0):

This sense of "bang" is generally transitive ([see Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bang)).

So you would say:

> Who wants this ball to bang them in the head?

Or, to use an idiom:

> Who wants a ball to the head?